# Getting the row that belongs to every cell with a certain string

Tags: excel

I'm not much of an Excel master, not sure if this is possible wtihout plugins (I have none installed at the moment).

I have an Excel document where from cell A to L I have a block of data.

Row A has the name of an item, Row G has the items' price
[image]

As you can see, the items are unordered in the table, is it possible to get every line where `A = Item1` and then use that to get all the prices? `G`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve that would be to just set a filter - Set the cursor to the header row, and select Data -- Filter. Then you can filter to your hearts content. (Consider adding the header row if you don't have one)

[image: Filter example]

Another way to achieve the same functionality is to select Home -- "Format as Table". Confusing name, but a bit more versatile.